nameId is invalid: fileId=362890, parentId=0, nameId=0
i have updated my android studio to latest version and installed some sdks but now iam trying to build my project which was working fine earlier it is showing error

nameId is invalid: fileId=362890, parentId=0, nameId=0



Please Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557](Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?) , Kindly provide more details and full stack trace of your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
